# cakephp: check controller action in model (beforeSave)

Tags: cakephp-2.0

Is there an easy way to check in the model which action was used in the controller to access the `beforeSave()` function?

I want to have another behavior if `beforeSave()` was called by edit vs. If it was called by add.

As a work around I used a hidden field in my form but I think that is not the most efficient way.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use your `$this->params['controller']` and `$this->params['action']`

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understand correctly.

```
function beforeSave() {
  if (!$this->id && !isset($this->data[$this->alias][$this->primaryKey])) {
    // insert
  } else {
    // edit
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Hey, at first thanks for your answer. To make it more clear: Let's say I use the save within the 'edit' action and within the 'add' action. I would like to know how I can check in the model (for example within before save) which action was used. In the controller I get this result using $this->action. I need that in the model.

Comment: I understand what you ask, but do not understand why, if we want to respect MVC. I know of no way to do what you need in CakePHP.

Comment: one possible solution is to create two functions to create and modify a model. Instead of save() on the controller, do so in the model

Comment: I simply used hidden fields in the corresponding view. That is an easy solution, not perfect though.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on stackoverflow when googling:

**Router::getParams()**

Output of this in a model will be:

```
array(5) {
  ["plugin"]=>
  NULL
  ["controller"]=>
  string(12) "cashflowrows"
  ["action"]=>
  string(5) "chart"
  ["named"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["pass"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Kevin's answer doesn't works in 1.3 but this one does.